# "Unexpected end of input" of the doctype tag when running AJAX asynchronous but not when synchronous

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous

I've got this project where I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` on line 1 of my HTML code, which is the DOCTYPE tag. I don't know how to fix this since the tag doesn't have a closing tag.. I only get this error when running the AJAX asynchronous, which I must do or the AJAX just gets stuck in an infinite loop manner.. I'm using this to interact with an API that grabs all the red days of a calendar year. Any ideas on how I fix this? I've been searching for an answer but I haven't found any that matches my problem.

Here's my AJAX code:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.dryg.net/dagar/v2/' + year, true);
        xhr.send();
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    for (item in json.dagar) {

        var propertyObject = json.dagar[item];

        for (subitem in propertyObject) {

            if (subitem === 'röd dag') {

                var redDay = propertyObject[subitem];

                if (redDay === 'Ja') {

                    calendar.markRedDays(propertyObject.datum);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <--- This is where the error points to
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online Calender</title>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Port+Lligat+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="firebase1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should read up on how async requests work with XMLHttpRequests: [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). You need to register a callback handler function: `httpRequest.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction`

Comment: @LcLk Should the callback function contain everything from <code>var json</code> and down? I've tried adding a callback but it didn't work and I'm a tad confused on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the response (xhr.responseText) is empty because the request is ascynchronous (it has not been received yet).

The method that throws that exception is JSON.parse.

A callback should be registered (as noted in the first comment on your question) to handle the response.

Please note that you should handle the case when the reposone is not JSON. For example, it may be an html page saying the an error has occured.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the truth is you need to learn how AJAX works and read the docs I [linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) in the comments.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.dryg.net/dagar/v2/' + year, true);
xhr.httpRequest.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;
xhr.send();
alert("this alert is triggered after the request was sent but before it returned")
```

Now the request is sent, and it will eventually return, but your code will keep on running through the normal flow. Once the request returns it will trigger the "onreadystatechange" event. Thanks to the line I added above this will call your callbackFunction. This should look as follows:

```
var callbackFunction = function(){

// This is the state when the xhr request has returned, see the docs
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
  // This means there was no error.
  if (xhr.status === 200) {

    //Here you can access the response of the xhr
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    for (item in json.dagar) {

        var propertyObject = json.dagar[item];

        for (subitem in propertyObject) {

            if (subitem === 'röd dag') {

                var redDay = propertyObject[subitem];

                if (redDay === 'Ja') {

                    calendar.markRedDays(propertyObject.datum);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  } else {
    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
  }
}
```

If it's still unclear look at the example on the MDN docs page